# SSRS how to have two different condition in Action Property

Tags: reporting-services

I am working in a SSRS that needs to link a report based on the value in a textbox.

I have tried:

```
=IIf(Fields!Factors.Value = "Touched Leads","SCPL",Nothing)
```

Which works fine, but when I try to add another condition like this:

```
=IIf(Fields!Factors.Value = "Touched Leads","SCPL",Nothing) OR 
    IIf(Fields!Factors.Value = "TOTAL","Disposition",Nothing)
```

Then it does not link any report. How do I do this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying does not work correctly as the `IIF` statements are not nested and what it is doing is:

```
IIF(this, true part, false part) OR IIF(this, true part, false part)
```

So when `Fields!Factors.Value = "Touched Leads"` the expression evalutes to `SCPL OR Nothing` which isn't valid.

Alternatively you could use `SWITCH` which has a nicer syntax, the final `True` statement is your catch all

```
=SWITCH(
    Fields!Factors.Value = "Touched Leads", "SCPL",
    Fields!Factors.Value = "TOTAL", "Disposition",
    True, Nothing
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the expression you need will look like this:

```
=IIf(Fields!Factors.Value = "Touched Leads","SCPL", 
    IIf(Fields!Factors.Value = "TOTAL","Disposition",Nothing))
```

This checks the first condition ("Touched Leads"), if that is true, link the SCPL report, otherwise check the "TOTAL" condition. If that one is false, return `Nothing`.